# Cannot find App_Start foler or update bundle config of ASP.NET MVC website in cpanel in live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, web-deployment, resourcebundle

I am deploying an ASP.NET mvc application in this hosting smarterasp.net. Currently my hosting plan is 60 days free trial. I got access to cPanel. Now I already successfully deployed my website on live server. But I want to change the Bundle config class, because I added new CSS files and want to reference it.

So I opened file manager from cpanel and find App_Data folder where bundle config class exists. But there is no App_Start folder in file manager as you can see below.

[image]

How can I edit my bundle config class? My hosting is Smarterasp. This is my first time of deploying an asp.net website on live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that the whole asp.net mvc web app gets compiled into a single dll. If you need to make an update, you should recompile and re-upload everything including the (web app name).dll file in your bin folder. If you just change code on the server, it won't reflect on the site.

Other than that, please provide some more info. Do you see the app_start folder on your local dev machine? What happens if you re-upload it?

Comment: Yes. But, best practice is to update everything so that you don't end up with code and dll in different versions.